# Solve this system of equations using elimination for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm taking an online Differential Equations class and don't understand how to solve this system of equations using elimination.

I tried the typical algebraic method but am running into trouble:

> $x'+y'-x=5$
>
> $x+y'+y=1$

So

$y=x'-2x-4$

$x=-5+x'+y'$

But I can't imagine this is how I leave the equation.  My guess is the equation should be in some form where I can use separation of variables or something, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you take the derivative of the second equation and now you have three equations to work with?

Comment: @Moo oh man I think you're right!  Thanks for that suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more basic than the good solution from Mhenni Benghorbal to whom all credit must be given.

Your system being $$x'+y'-x=5\tag 1$$ $$x+y'+y=1\tag 2$$ From $(2)$, extract $x$ $$x=1-y-y'\tag 3$$ Differentiate to get $$x'=-y'-y''\tag 4$$ Plug $x$ from $(3)$ and $x'$ from $(4)$ into $(1)$ to get $$-y'-y''+y'-1+y+y'=5\tag 5$$ that is to say $$-y''+y'+y=6 \tag 6$$ Solve $(6)$ for $y$ and plug the result in $(3)$ to get $x$ directly.

Comment: So I did what you said and I got $x=1-y''+y-6$ and $y=y''-y'-y+6$ but I don't understand why these are 'solutions' to the question.  Would you mind elaborating for me?  Is it because they are linear solutions in terms of one variable?  I just want to understand.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just write the system as

> $$(D-1)x+Dy=5\\
> x+(D+1)y=1$$

where $D=\frac{d} {dx} $. Applying the differential operator $- (D-1)$ to the second equation and adding both equations gives the equation

> $$  -(D^2-1)y+Dy=6 \implies y''-y'-y=6. $$

I think you can finish it!

Comment: @Moo Yes it should be!  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @downvoter it is corrected!

Comment: @Moo typos are expected!  The most important thing is the idea and the techniques!  Th OP has to take care of these things!!

Comment: It is just ridiculous (and even more) to see, once more, a downvote for a good answer !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It is just an immature act!