# How to solve systems of second order differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Could you please let me know a video or website that shows how to solve a system of second order differential equations like this?
[image]

Comment: One technique consists in rewriting the second-order system in a first-order system of larger size (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732759/solve-a-system-of-second-order-differential-equations) post).